# Power Query - extracting data from nested lists

Tags: powerquery, m

I have several [JSON files](https://github.com/telegeography/www.submarinecablemap.com/tree/master/public/api/v2/cable) that I need to combine in power query. Ever file has the same structure that needs to be pivoted. Here's [link to the files](https://equinix.box.com/s/h2aiaoqd5pyvfvek0rlr2rt1gmeronat)

I'm struggling as each file has a column contains a list of records, that prevents power query from pivoting the table.

Here are two screenshots of how it looks like in the query editor, I just need to extract the "landing_points.name" from the list and pivot the whole table into a format like the second screenshot.

How can I do this? any help is greatly appreciated!

Below is the code I used, and got this error message

An error occurred in the ‘Transform File’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Record.
Details:
Value=[List]
Type=[Type]

[Row 93 error reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwG5p.png)

```
let
Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\ldu\Desktop\Subsea"),
#"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
#"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
#"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Name", type any}, {"Value", type any}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 9), Int64.Type}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Integer-Divided Column", List.Distinct(#"Integer-Divided Column"[Name]), "Name", "Value")
```

in
#"Pivoted Column"

[Nested lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4CkO.png)

[Extracted if just pulling one file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBZwg.png)

Comment: sorry, I just cant get the files out of box

Comment: You could go to this page and click on "code" to download the file, and the files are in this folder: public/api/v2/cable/

https://github.com/telegeography/www.submarinecablemap.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

We create an index. Use integer divide to group by filename. Pivot. Expand the list then pull out the name field from the record

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\ldu\Desktop\Subsea"),
#"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
#"RecordToTable" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File from Query1", each Record.ToTable(Json.Document([Content]))),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(RecordToTable,{"Name", "Transform File from Query1"}),
#"Expanded Transform File from Query1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Transform File from Query1", {"Name", "Value"}, {"Name1", "Value"}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded Transform File from Query1", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 9), Int64.Type}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Integer-Divided Column", List.Distinct(#"Integer-Divided Column"[Name1]), "Name1", "Value"),
#"Expanded landing_points" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "landing_points"),
#"ExtractName" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded landing_points",{{"landing_points", each   Record.Field(_,"name"), type text}})
in  #"ExtractName"
```

If that still doesn't work then try this which does the expansion before the pivot

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\ldu\Desktop\Subsea"),
#"RecordToTable" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Transform File from Query1", each Record.ToTable(Json.Document([Content]))),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(RecordToTable,{"Name", "Transform File from Query1"}),
#"Expanded Transform File from Query1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Transform File from Query1", {"Name", "Value"}, {"Name1", "Value"}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded Transform File from Query1", "Index", 0, 1),

// extract and combine landing points locations
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Name1] = "landing_points"),
#"Expanded Value" = Table.TransformColumns(Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Value"),{{"Value", each Record.Field(_,"name"), type text}}),
Places = Table.Group(#"Expanded Value", {"Name","Index","Name1"}, {{"Value", each Text.Combine([Value],"|"), type text}}),

Recombined = Table.Sort(Table.Combine({Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Name1] <> "landing_points"), Places }),{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),

#"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(Recombined  , {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 9), Int64.Type}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Integer-Divided Column", List.Distinct(#"Integer-Divided Column"[Name1]), "Name1", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Pivoted Column", {{"landing_points", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "landing_points")
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Comment: thank you, but I got the following error. What should I replace "value" with? thanks again

Expression.Error: The column 'Value' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Value

Comment: Your sample screenshot clearly shows Value as a column name, so I don't know what is the issue.  Try to follow the steps I gave instead of copying the code directly and it will build the code for you

Comment: Thank you, I followed the steps but got the following error after doing the column pivot (with dont aggregate)

An error occurred in the ‘Transform File’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Record.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]

Comment: Edit question, post code and if possible post copy of source file data in excel format somewhere and post link to that file

Comment: Thank you. I added the code and hyperlink to the files (original source). I don't know where I can post the files and link back to here but will look into this in a moment....

Comment: Just added link to the files

Comment: can you post the custom function this calls?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by custom function this calls?

Comment: I cannot use the code you provided to test because this row errors out: #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),    because you are not providing the code behind the #"Transform File"([Content]) command

Comment: I see what you are saying, that row comes up right after after I pulled the files from folder, and clicked on the double arrows atop the "Content" column to expand the details. How do I get the code behind the #trasnformfiles? Again, thanks for your help and patience...

Comment: horseyride, thanks for the continued support. I used the updated code but still got the error message

Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Record.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]

Comment: I got the error when pivoting based on the name column. Is there a way to extract the landing point names before doing the pivot? I feel that may address the limitation but not sure how to do it....:(

Comment: last try in text above

Comment: I'm getting the same error code (attached at the end of the message) at the "Places = Table.Sort..." step. The "Expanded Value" step seems fine but the table shows errors from row 93 (screenshot added to the original post)

Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Record.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]

Comment: your data has errors. Find which file is breaking it and verify the JSON

Comment: Hey horseyride, thanks so much for helping me out and your patience. You were right about it's a data issue, I began to bootstrap the files and identify the one file that's causing issue and removed it, and then your code works! thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, didn't know how to do that